# Windows 10 changes to hosts file ignored

Tags: windows-10, hosts-file

I modified the Windows hosts file under C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc.
I added the line

```
xxx.yyy.xxx.18  jira.example.com
```

but the entry is simple ignored..
I also tried deactivating the Virus protection (Avira) but I have no idea what to try next..

Is there a windows group policy which deactivate/ignore the hosts file?

To be clear, the file is saved in the right position, but the changes itself are ignored.

Comment: "Is there a windows group policy which deactivate/ignore the hosts file?" - There is not.  Something else is going on.

Comment: Not 100% sure but after the changes, did you restart the PC? (and I'm assuming you have confirmed the changes are saved, and reopening the file do show the content of the changes)

Comment: How did you test to see if it works? Browsers only? Or did you also try pinging it?

Comment: I tried restarting, but no effect
The file is changed (i confirmed it, so its no resetting of the file or something differen)
Tested if it works was done by pinging.

Comment: I've just checked a W10 system which had a `hosts` file modified before I upgraded from W8.1, and all the additions work, including some that map to addresses that are no longer valid, and `ping` maps the addresses correctly, though there is no response of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to the AntiVirus Software "AVIRA"
They have a setting for enabling/disabling HOST file protection, but this was broken. It always was enabled.
Also disabling the antivirus didn't help.

Solution was:
Uninstalling AntiVirus, change HOST file, reinstalling AntiVirus.

Answer (score 0):

Open a Command Prompt as Administrator and run:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure, you have edited the correct path of hots file,
because I have experienced edited hosts file in windows.old folder, that folder exist because I just re-install my windown 10
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUKnq.png)

thanks